# How to authenticate multiple active directory user on single application in azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have created two active directory in azure  which connect with two different local active directory (two different companey)

I Have application in which i want both azure active  directory user can login on same instance of application i don't want to host two instance of application .

After authentication i need to to check from which active directory user belongs .

Any Help would be really appreciated since i am struggling from last three days

Comment: Thats a multi tenant application from the maad/waad perspective. Try google that until i have time to give an in depth answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a multi-tenant application, like pksorensen's comment states. Essentially what you want to do is register the application in one of your directories and update its configuration to make it multi-tenant capable (discussed in the links below). When a user from another directory signs in to the application, your app starts a consent flow by hitting Azure AD's common authentication endpoint (different from your tenant-specific one), and then displays a consent dialog. After the user consents, Azure AD registers the application in the other directory.

All the information you need about implementing this scenario:

- [Brand new code sample for a multi-tenant web application with sign-on](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet)
- [Info about multi-tenant apps, how to make an application multi-tenant, and the consent experience](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx)
- The [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx) topic and its [Web Browser to Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx#BKMK_Browser) section that describes the technical details of the protocol flow and how it all works