# Is it feasible to have a centralized place that handles authentication for all applications, or should authentication be app specific?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I would like to offer multiple solutions on App Source and each solution will have authentication.

I am considering of having a centralized place where all authentication is being handled. This centralized place will be a Web API, that is configured with Open Id Connect and it calls the AAD endpoint to allow the user to sign in and receive back tokens (id and access tokens). These tokens will all be handled (i.e. stored/expired/refreshed) within this Web API.

Every application will leverage this API and on each request will call the API and the API will validate the token which is currently being stored locally and refresh/expire tokens as needed.

Is this a feasible/viable solution? Should authentication be kept app-specific?

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a multi-tenant application, rather than building something custom. You would register the application in one of your directories and update its configuration to make it a multi tenant app and SSO your users. [How to authenticate multiple active directory user on single application in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897849/how-to-authenticate-multiple-active-directory-user-on-single-application-in-azur)

If all of your users are in the same tenant anyway, then you can just do tenant specific authentication rather than adding users to particular apps.

What is the use case for the scenario you described? It sounds a bit like reinventing the wheel since Azure handles this already.